# No bean named but bean is defined

Tags: java, spring, grails, groovy, spring-security

I'm working on an update version of grail-oauth-plugin that support last spring-oauth

My plugin version works good and I have implemented a workin oauth2 server.

But now I want to add a custom-grant defined like this

```
def doWithSpring = {

    myTokenGranter(MyTokenGranter)

    xmlns oauth:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"

    oauth.'authorization-server'( /* ... many definitions here ... */){
        /* ... many definitions here ... */
        oauth.'custom-grant'('token-granter-ref': "myTokenGranter")
    }
}
```

But I get an exception telling me:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'myTokenGranter'
```

But the bean myTokenGranter is defined as you can see. And If I remove the custom-grant definition the project starts and I can access the myTokenGranter bean.

Looking to a fullstack trace I see that the exception occur in the [spring oatuh2 server bean definition parse  AuthorizationServerBeanDefinitionParser.java](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/AuthorizationServerBeanDefinitionParser.java) in the line where it try to find my bean

```
parserContext.getRegistry().getBeanDefinition(customGranterRef);
```

where customGranterRef = "myTokenGranter"

so I suspect there is a bug in Spring Ouath or in Grails BeanBuilder that does not let my "myTokenGranter" to be visible in the server parser. Or making some error in grails bean definition DSL.

---

Thank you for your interest.

Debugging the app more deeply I have found that the problem probably is in how grails BeanBuilder work in translating namespaced spring DSL.

If I debug the point where my bean is checked (in [AuthorizationServerBeanDefinitionParser.java](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/AuthorizationServerBeanDefinitionParser.java))

at row

```
parserContext.getRegistry().getBeanDefinition(customGranterRef);
```

if I check che result of

```
 parserContext.getRegistry().getBeanDefinitionNames()
```

it show me only this beans

```
[org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor
 org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor
 org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor
 org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor
 org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor
 org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator
 org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0
 org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor
 oauth2TokenGranter
 oauth2AuthorizationCodeServices
 oauth2AuthorizationRequestManager]
```

And not all other decleared beans...

---

The problem exist even if I move the ouath server declaration inside resources.xml, keeping my custom token granter bean declaration inside resources.groovy.

But the problem solves if I move the custom token bean declaration inside resources.xml.

Comment: did u try to post in spring-security-oauth forum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved hacking Spring Security Oauth

see this [commit](https://github.com/ftaiolivista/spring-security-oauth/commit/90c7337f4b08eb41852cfab4a44c76b2639246b7)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how the BeanBuilder DSL works, but it seems like the problem is there if there is a problem (your example works just fine in XML).  Can you do it in two steps, so the bean definition for myTokenGranter is definitely available when the OAuth2 namepsace is handled?

Comment: What do you mean with "two steps"?